# Storing a username & password for a REST API in a web app session

Tags: security, rest, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, basic-authentication

We have built a REST API.  The API is built, and working, and uses basic authentication for every request.

We now wish to build other web applications that use the REST API.  We're having issues working out how to do authentication in the web app, however.

Ideally, we want the web application to display a login page, and the user will enter in their credentials for the REST API.  The problem is that once the user is "logged in" to the web application, how and where does the web application store the entered credentials, bearing in mind that it **will need to store them** in order to submit the credentials to the REST API when it needs to make any further request.

Modern web browsers must do something similar, no?  When we access the REST API in the browser, it asks us for the username and password once, but subsequent requests resubmit the credentials we entered earlier.  How can we replicate this in a web app?  I'm assuming that storing them in the session is a bad idea...?

-- Edit

It's probably worth pointing out that the requests to the REST API will be made from the server, so not looking to store them on client-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you're probably going about this wrong. If you have some business requirement to submit a username and password with every request, you should probably find the person who made the requirement and try very hard to talk some sense into them.  There is simply no reason for it.  That is what sessions are for.

You authenticate a user exactly once.  Upon authentication, you give that user a session.  You no longer need to authenticate because the session tells you who the user is.

Getting a user to enter their credentials with every request will annoy the living daylights out of them.  Storing it client side (in cookies or local storage) is problematic and has serious security implications.  In all cases, sending a username/password pair across the wire with every request (while theoretically secure over https) is just a bad idea. This is pretty much the iconic use case for sessions, use them.

Comment: But surely the whole point of a REST API is that its stateless?  By adding a session, aren't you making it stateful and defeating any point in having a RESTful API...?

Comment: @dark_perfect You are pushing the "stateless" concept too far. Authentication/authorization is often not the point of your REST service. It is a prerequisite. This is why the security added to REST services is often implemented in a different layer/library, and the REST service simply invokes that layer to verify the identity and rights of the user AFTER the user has been authenticated.

Comment: Sessions don't seem like the way to go though.  ASP.Net Web API (which is what the REST API was built with) wasn't even designed to support sessions.

Comment: Would it be considered bad practice to store the username and password in the website's session?  It would still be stored server side but there's another node that has knowledge of the credentials so it's slightly less secure, I suppose.  Perhaps using a SecureString object would be best in this case?

Comment: @dark_perfect There is generally not a good reason for the server storing the user's password in a session.  Just knowing who the user is should be good enough.

Comment: But in this case the server needs to know both, right? How else would it be able to make any requests to the REST API without knowing both?

Comment: @dark_perfect a password is used for authenticating. Sessions are active for as long as the user is in a web browser or stored in a cookie. API calls are granted to users who are authenticated already. Checking whether the user is allowed into the system is a DB design where they have a status in one of the tables (true/false) and then you check that. Or if the user was authenticated from another place, you store that IP address and compare with the current one.